# MongoDB save entries the other way round

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use NodeJS and I have a MongoDB collection with a lot of entries. 99% of time the last entry is selected, sometimes the entry before. Since MongoDB has to get through all entries one by one, it would be more useful to sort the entries the other way round:
Instead of this:

```
{
    _id: "foo",
    name: "name"
},
{
    _id: "bar",
    name: "name"
}
// <- new entry will be inserted here
```

I want to use this:

```
// <- new entry will be inserted here
{
    _id: "foo",
    name: "name"
},
{
    _id: "bar",
    name: "name"
},
```

So that in most cases the entry I search for is the first or the second item.

Is that possible or even necessary (does it make any difference in speed)?

I could also reverse the items and then iterate through them, but I don't think that this would be faster.

Comment: You haven't shown your query code

Comment: What do you mean by "the last entry"? How are you ordering the documents? If you want the last inserted item, ordering on the `_id` field corresponds fairly well with creation time, so you can use `db.collection.find().sort({ "_id" : -1 }).limit(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You schould not be concerned about position of the item in the collection. Each collection has an index on _id field so if you sort your collection by this field and take first (second or third) element you will get in in no time ( porbably 0 ms)

Comment: Do you mean for example calling .sort(..) after .find(..)?

Comment: Yes, db.collection.find().sort({"_id":-1}) will use an index. Next u can limit the result set to 1, 2 or 3 elements. By using limit method i.e limit(1). Since it will use index you will get the results straightaway.  db.collection.find().sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1)